# <noscript> or something else

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, graceful-degradation

I have a site that relies heavily on JavaScript and uses jQuery throughout.

I'm not going to attempt to make the site work for those who don't have JavaScript enabled.

However, I would like to show a banner at the top of the page which tells them the site is intended for use with JavaScript enabled and perhaps a modern browser, etc.

I was thinking of just putting a PHP include on all pages that contains a <noscript> with the banner inside that. Is this is good approach or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<noscript>` is the way to go.

You should also provide links to other, better browsers in the `<noscript>` tag if you can detect that's a browser without JavaScript.

If you wish to be more drastic about it, start with the markup `<body class="nojs">` and, onload remove that class with JavaScript.

You could then have `body.nojs #wrapper { display: none; }, body.nojs #notice { display: block }` in your CSS.

Comment: Do you recommend any libraries (php) for browser detection?

Comment: I tried http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/ without any problems..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *[How to know and handle disabled JavaScript in the browser](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/how-to-know-handle-disabled-javascript.html)* can help you.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely one alternative...

Another is to have the banner visible by default without using `noscript` and then a `$().ready()` which hides the banner for all JavaScript enabled browsers.